# Sphere not respecting gravity outside plane geometry

Tags: react-three-fiber

I have this simple environment with a sphere and a plane. Both of the objects are wrapped within a Physics component and the physics work, if I remove the plane the sphere will fall. But when I run the sphere outside the plane, the sphere does not fall. I don't know if I have misunderstood something trivial, maybe the plane is wider than what it looks like for example?

I don't think there is a way to set the width/depth of the mesh, so I assume it is the width/depth of the planeBufferGeometry that counts?

[image]
main.js:

```js
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { Sky, PointerLockControls } from '@react-three/drei'
import { Physics } from '@react-three/cannon'
import { Ground, Sphere } from '../components/'

export default function Game(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Canvas shadows colorManagement camera={{ fov: 45 }}>
        <Sky sunPosition={[100, 10, 100]} />
        <ambientLight intensity={0.3} />
        <pointLight castShadow intensity={2.8} position={[100, 100, 100]} />
        <Physics gravity={[0, -106, 0]}>
          <Ground />
          <Sphere />
        </Physics>
        <PointerLockControls />
      </Canvas>
    </>
  )
}
```

Ground.js:

```js
import { usePlane } from '@react-three/cannon'
import { useNormalTexture } from '@react-three/drei'

export default function Ground(props) {
  const [ref] = usePlane(() => ({ rotation: [-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0], ...props }))

  const [normalMap] = useNormalTexture(32, {
    offset: [0, 0],
    repeat: [100, 100],
    anisotropy: 8
  })

  return (
    <mesh ref={ref} receiveShadow>
      <planeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[50, 50]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial
        attach="material"
        normalMap={normalMap}
        color="#dadb84"
      />
    </mesh>
  )
}
```

Comment: I mean I'm quite proud of the looks of it, but disrespectful yes indeed!